# Minecraft Bukkit Plugin, runTask(Plugin plugin)

Tags: java, plugins, bukkit

i try to make a minecraft plugin with bukkit and i will try to change the time every 500ms but when i start that in the main thread, the server crashes. So i tried the runTask(); function but i do not know where i can find the parameter Plugin, because it says it needs runTask(Plugin plugin);.
Here is my code:

dayNight file:

```
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.World;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin;
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitTask;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class dayNight implements CommandExecutor
{

    public void sleep(int time)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(time);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void changeTimeEvent(CommandSender sender, int time)
    {
        sender.getServer().getWorld("world").setTime(time);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args)
    {
        Plugin plugin;
        new dayNightTask().runTask(plugin);
```

and the dayNightTask file:

```
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.World;
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitRunnable;

public class dayNightTask extends BukkitRunnable
{

    public void sleep(int time)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(time);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        World world = Bukkit.getWorld("world");
        for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
        {
            world.setTime(0);
            sleep(500);
            world.setTime(16000);
            sleep(500);
        }
    }
}
```

I do not know how i can find the plugin parameter for the runTask(); function, please help :)
best regards

Answer (score 1):

Spigot include own timer task. You should **NEVER** use `Thread.sleep()` on spigot, and less in main thread. Here you are just totally blocking the main thread.

You should use `Bukkit.getScheduler()`.

1. Use `Runnable` instead of `BukkitRunnable`
2. Use method showed in [documentation](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/scheduler/BukkitScheduler.html). In your case, [`runTaskLater`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/scheduler/BukkitScheduler.html#runTaskLater(org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin,java.lang.Runnable,long)) should answer
3. Finally, this is what you will have in your `dayNightTask` class:

```java
public class dayNightTask implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        World world = Bukkit.getWorld("world");
        for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
            world.setTime(0);
            Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(MyPlugin.getInstance(), () ->  world.setTime(16000), 10);
        }
    }
}
```

10 is in tick. 20 ticks = 1 second, if you want each 0.5 second, you want each 10 ticks.

Now, in your command, you should use :

```java
Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskTimer(plugin, new dayNightTask(), delay);
```

PS: The plugin instance should the object of the class that extends `JavaPlugin`. Such as said in [documentation](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/spigot-plugin-development/) ([Eclipse](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/creating-a-blank-spigot-plugin-in-eclipse/), [Intellij Idea](http://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/creating-a-blank-spigot-plugin-in-intellij-idea/) ...) you should have a class that `extendds JavaPlugin`.

You should save the instance of this, you can do this in 2 ways:

1. Pass object into constructor, for example: `new dayNight(this)` then in the constructor, do :

```java
private JavaPlugin plugin;

public dayNight(JavaPlugin pl) {
   this.plugin = pl;
}
```

2. Create a static class :

```java
// declare object and method
private static JavaPlugin instance;
public static JavaPlugin getInstance() {
   return instance;
}

@Override
public void onEnable() { // this class should already exist
   instance = this; // set instance as current object
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried it but I have the same problem with the "plugin". What do you mean with "PS: The plugin instance should the object of the class that extends JavaPlugin"? In my code now is the error message "Cannot resolve symbol 'plugin' " and I don't know how to solve that, I am new in Minecraft Plugin programming.

Comment: I just add some explaination to my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `Executors` in java. They're asynchron and easy to use.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html